# EXCEL: Find sum of values in one column with criteria from other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

[image: Excel sample]
Hi I would like to know how I can calculate the total amount of purchase for a specific person.

The data sheet is given in the image above. I would like to count the total purchase for the names in Column D from Column B.

I am stuck as to what excel formula I should use.

Appreciate the help!

I tried using SUMIF with VLOOKUP inside but it doesn't seem reasonable to use.

Comment: Just SUMIF should do it, SUMIF has your SUM range and your criteria where  your criteria range is your A:A and criteria is your $D2 (for cell E2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$11;D2;$B$2:$B$11)
```

SUMIF is the only function you need. You need to put an interval of all the names you are going to check and fix both the column and the row, then you put the name you need and since you have them written in another column just chose the first name and don't fix it. Lastly, you need the range of the cost again fixated.

Comment: E2 being D2 and $C$2:$C$11 being $B$2:$B11, right? :p

Comment: @Notus_Panda Of course. I've misunderstood what's written. I thought that he meant that the names are in column B, meaning he's shown column B, C, D, E, F on the picture. Thanks, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I was wrong myself, I was thinking of SUMIFS where the SUM range is put first, glad you caught my mistake as well.

Comment: That works, I must've overcomplicated things in my mind. The answer was right in front of me. Thanks so much!